# Meteor blaze rendered twice

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have seen similar questions, but could not apply it to my case...

I got a route define with `iron-router`:

```
this.route('home', {
  path: '/',
  template: 'home',
  waitOn: function(){
    return [Meteor.subscribe('books'),Meteor.subscribe('authors'))];
  },
onBeforeAction: function(){
  Session.set('search_keywords', this.params.search);
  }
});
```

On my `home.js` file I got a helper to display `books` like this:

```
Template.booksList.helpers({
  books: function () {
    if(Session.get("search_keywords")){
      keywords = new RegExp(Session.get("search_keywords"), "i");
      var result = Books.find({$or:[{name:keywords},{description:keywords},{tags:keywords}]},{sort: {updatedAt: 1}});
      if(result.count()===0){
         console.log('no results found')
         return [];
      }else{
        return result;
      }
    }
   }
 });
```

and on `home.html`:

```
<template name="booksList">
 <div class="row">
  {{#each books}}  
    {{> bookDetail}}
  {{/each}}
 </div>
</template>
```

The aim is to access the view from an url like `http://mydomain.com/?search=Happy%20Potter` to find all Harry Potter books.

Something I don't understand... the page is rendered twice, first saying there is no result then displaying the result.
Do you see why?

Thanks !

Comment: yes, that's normal. If you don't like that, then you can look into the `loadTemplate` option of iron-router. It will show a different template until the data you `waitOn`has arrived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the docs for iron-router. In particular, this section on the WaitOn hook where it describes use of the loadingTemplate.

See: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/dev/DOCS.md#waiting-on-subscriptions-waiton

You can set the loadingTemplate similar to the way you set the template for the route. For example,

this.route('home', {
  path: '/',
  template: 'home',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
...

The loadingTemplate will be displayed until your data is ready and then the data from the subscription will be rendered in your main 'home' template.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Did not imagine it was coming from there...

Also, since Blaze, you need to add `Router.onBeforeAction('loading');` as describe here https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/dev/README.md#controlling-subscriptions